# C# VS2012 inherited forms menu

Tags: c#, inheritance, visual-studio-2012

I've created the BaseForm with a Menu and added some functions.

menuStrip and toolStrip have Modifiers set to public. Every item that I click in the strips has modifiers set to public.

In InheritedForm I can edit all elements of BaseForm which have Modifiers=Public, apart from menuStrip and toolStrip.

Why is that so and where can I fix it?

Comment: The designers are just not smart enough to handle this.  Consider the ability to merge menus and tool strips as a workaround.